# Testing angular provider with $http success block

Tags: angularjs

**Edited to include test:**

I've got an angular app with a controller like:

```
anuglar.module('myModule')
.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myProvider', 
  function($scope, myprovider){
    $scope.api = myProvider(objectName);
    $scope.sites = $scope.api.list();
  }]);
```

That utilizes a provider like the below.

```
angular.module('myProviders')
.provider('myProvider', function(){
  var url = 'http://localhost:3000/path/to/api';
  this.$get = ['$http', function($http){
    return function(){
      return {
        list: function(){
          var list=[];
          $http.get(url).success(function(data){
            list = data;
          });
          return list;
        }
      }
    };
  }];
});
```

The test:

```
describe('cqsdbProvider', function () {
  var mockCqsdbProvider, $httpBackend;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('tgr1202App'));

  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.inject(function($injector){
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      mockCqsdbProvider = $injector.get('cqsdbProvider');
    });
  });

  describe('list', function(){
    it('should get a list of sites', inject(function(cqsdbProvider){
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/path/to/api').
      respond('[{"name":"Test1"}]');

      var provider = mockCqsdbProvider();
      var thing = provider.list();
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(thing.length).toEqual(1);
    }));
  });
});
```

This code behaves as expected in the browser, but the tests fail saying thing length is zero. I know success isn't finishing, so the empty array is being returned, I just don't know how to tell my mock to wait for a response.

Comment: Please share the test you have written.

Comment: Added the test in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be problem with your implementation. Can you try

```
 list: function(){
          var list=[];
          $http.get(url).success(function(data){
            list.length = 0;
            list.push(data);
          });
          return list;
        }
```